# How to get the look up(containing multiple columns) column values into a variable using REST API and Jquery in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-jsom

/* in the same way I need to get values from look up column which consisting of multiple columns from another list into a variable  */
url : _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Cities')/items?$select=Country/Title&$expand=Country/Title",

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got the results in data.d.results.

```
var results=data.d.results;
displayObjectProperty("getData",results,"Title");
function displayObjectProperty(id,object,Property){
                for(var x in object)
                {
                              if(typeof(object[x]) == "object"){displayObjectProperty(id,object[x],Property)}else{
                              if(x==Property){
                                              document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<b>" + x + "</b>"+"::<i>" + object[x] + "</i>";
                }
                }
                }

        }
```